# set binding for visible property using 2 values in Xamarin forms code behind

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, multibinding

I have a list which contains Label in it. List View is declared in XAML file where list's Data-cell is generated programmatically in cs file. I need to bind visible property for this label in the list based on the 2 fields values.

Xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvItemSigns" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Gray">
```

cs file code:

```
lvItemSigns.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataCell)); 
lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = VM.ItemSignsList;

class DataCell : ViewCell
{
Label label;
public DataCell()
{
 // has grid
  var label = new Label();
        label.TextColor = Color.Black;
        label.Margin = 4;
        label.Text = "test";
        grid.Children.Add(label, 2, 1);
        label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new 
Binding("SubItem", BindingMode.TwoWay, new 
BooleanConverter(), null, null, "cs-file_name"));
 grid.Children.Add(stackLayout, 0, 3);

        grid.Margin = new Thickness(8,0,0,0);
        View = grid;
   }
}
```

I'm able to bind the visible property using 1 value, how to accomplish by using 2 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a read-only property on your model

```
public bool Visible 
{
  get
  {
    // test for multiple conditions here
    return PropertyA && PropertyB;
  }
}
```

you will also need to raise `PropertyChanged("Visible")` whenever the values of any dependent properties are set.

Comment: Is this correct?   private bool _deleteItemIconVisible;
        public bool DeleteItemIconVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return RecordID == 0 && SyncError;
            }
            set
            {
                _deleteItemIconVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("DeleteItemIconVisible");
            }
        }   @Jason

Comment: you don't need a `set` and there's really no reason to have a private variable since the `get` never uses it